What is wrong in my solution for the following PDE $u_x^2+u_y^2=1$ with boundary value?
I am asked to solve the boundary value problem on a PDE about $u:\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}^2\cap \{(x,y): x^2+y^2\ge 1\}\to\mathbb{R}$:
$$
\begin{cases}
u_x^2+u_y^2=1 & x^2+y^2>1,\, x,y>0\\
u(\cos s,\sin s)=s & s\in (0,\frac{\pi}{2})
\end{cases}
$$
I followed the way of solving characteristic ODE as is described on Evans's textbook.
But I got the absurd result that $u(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\arctan(\frac yx)-1$, which does not satisfy $u_x^2+u_y^2=1$.
I do not know what is wrong.
My solution: Set $F(p_x,p_y,z,x,y)=p_x^2+p_y^2-1$. Then the characteristic ODE is
\begin{align*}
(p_x'(s),p_y'(s))&=-D_xF-D_zF\cdot \vec{p}=0.\\
z'(s)&=D_pF\cdot\vec{p}=2(p_x^2+p_y^2)=2.\\
(x'(s),y'(s))&=D_pF=(2p_x,2p_y).
\end{align*}
The first equation says $p_x,p_y$ are constant. Therefore we may set (since $p_x^2+p_y^2=1$)
$$ p_x(s)\equiv \cos\theta, \, p_y(s)\equiv \sin\theta\, (\forall s).  $$
Then by the third equation we have $x(s)=2s\cos\theta$, $y(s)=2s\sin\theta$.
Finally, since $z'(s)=2$ we have $u(x(s),y(s))=z(s)=2s+z^0$.
By letting $s=\frac 12$ we have $1+z^0=u(\cos \theta,\sin\theta)=\theta$.
Hence $z^0=\theta-1=\arctan(\frac yx)-1$.
Thus
\begin{multline*}
u(x,y)= u(2s\cos\theta,2s\sin\theta)=\\
2s+z^0=2s+ \arctan(\frac yx)-1=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\arctan(\frac yx)-1.
\end{multline*}
But $u(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+\arctan(\frac yx)-1$ does not satisfy $u_x^2+u_y^2=1$. What is wrong with my solution?

A good question!

@HansLundmark Sorry, I will fix that.

The solutions to the characteristic ODEs are$^{(*)}$
\begin{align}
p_x(t)&=a, \tag{1.1} \\
p_y(t)&=b, \tag{1.2} \\
x(t)&=x_0+2at, \tag{1.3} \\
y(t)&=y_0+2bt, \tag{1.4} \\
u(t)&=u_0+2t. \tag{1.5}
\end{align}
The boundary condition $u(\cos s,\sin s)=s$ is equivalent to
\begin{align}
x_0&=\cos s, \tag{2.1} \\
y_0&=\sin s, \tag{2.2} \\
u_0&=s. \tag{2.3}
\end{align}
In addition,
\begin{align}
a&=p_x(0)=\frac{\partial u_0}{\partial x_0}=-\frac{y_0}{x_0^2+y_0^2}=-\sin s, \tag{3.1} \\
b&=p_y(0)=\frac{\partial u_0}{\partial y_0}=\frac{x_0}{x_0^2+y_0^2}=\cos s. \tag{3.2}
\end{align}
Combining $(1)$, $(2)$ and $(3)$, we get
\begin{align}
x(t)&=\cos s - 2t\sin s, \tag{4.1} \\
y(t)&=\sin s + 2t\cos s, \tag{4.2} \\
u(t)&=s+2t. \tag{4.3}
\end{align}
It follows from $(4.1)$ and $(4.2)$ that
$$
x^2+y^2=1+4t^2 \implies t=\pm\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{x^2+y^2-1}, \tag{5}
$$
and
$$
\frac{y}{x}=\frac{\sin s+2t\cos s}{\cos s-2t\sin s}=\frac{\tan s+2t}{1-2t\tan s}
=\tan(s+\varphi)
$$
$$
\implies s=-\varphi+\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right), \tag{6}
$$
where
$$
\tan\varphi=2t=\pm\sqrt{x^2+y^2-1} \implies 
\varphi=\pm\arctan\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2-1}\right). \tag{7}
$$
Plugging $(5)$-$(7)$ into $(4.3)$ we finally obtain
$$
u(x,y)=\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\pm\left[\sqrt{x^2+y^2-1}
-\arctan\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2-1}\right)\right]. \tag{8}
$$

$^{(*)}$ I have replaced the parameter $s$ with $t$ in the characteristic curves because $s$ is already used as a parameter in the boundary condition.

+1. But there are some subtleties. The given data don't determine $u(x,y)$ uniquely in the whole positive quadrant. For a given point $(x,y)$ in the positive quadrant (and with $x^2+y^2>1$), what you have to do geometrically to find out which (projected) characteristic is lies on is to find a tangent line to the “positive unit quartercircle” ($x^2+y^2=1$, $x>0$, $y>0$) which passes through that point $(x,y)$; the point of tangency will then be $(\cos s, \sin s)$, where $u$ is given.

For such points $(x,y)$ lying in the strip $0 < x < 1$, there's a unique way of going down right to touch the quarter circle;
for points in the strip $0 < y < 1$, there's a unique way of going up left, for points in the unit square where these two
strips overlap there are two tangents, and for points such that $x \ge 1$ and $y \ge 1$ there are no tangents.

So you get one solution which is uniquely determined in the first strip, and another solution which is uniquely determined in the other strip, and both of these solutions can be continued non-uniquely to the whole quadrant (by assigning data as you wish on the parts of the unit circle which lies in the fourth or second quadrant, respectively).

An afterthough regarding the last part of my previous comment: It's not quite as easy as I first imagined, since if you assign something else than $u(\cos s, \sin s)=s$ for $-\pi/2 < s \le 0$, say), then you're going to change $p_x(0)$ and $p_y(0)$, so the characteristics won't be the same as before. But the point about non-uniqueness still remains.

At the very least, if you assign boundary values $u(\cos s, \sin s)=s$ for $-\pi < s < \pi$, then you get two different almost global solutions, $$u(x,y) = R + \arg\Bigl((x+Ry)+i(y-Rx)\Bigr), \qquad R = \pm\sqrt{x^2+y^2-1}.$$ They are defined in the whole region $x^2+y^2 \ge 1$, except that the solution with the plus sign in $R$ has a jump discontinuity along the ray $x=-1$, $y \le 0$, and the solution with the minus sign jumps along the ray $x=-1$, $y \ge 0$. But they both solve the original problem in the positive quadrant (and they are not equal there).

(And your solutions (8) agree with these in the right half-plane.)

@HansLundmark Thanks for your complement. I asked my tutor who gave me the problem and he said he meant finding one solution of the problem.

It seems the difference between your solution and my solution is that, except for $t$, the variable of the system of equations, how many constant should be introduced. I only introduced two ($\theta,, z_0$) while you introduced for each variable ($p_x,p_y,x,y,z$) one constant respectively. Is it true that we should introduce for each variable a constant? This seems making the calculation a bit heavy, but it indeed yields the correct result.

There are 5 first order characteristic ODEs, hence there are 5 integration constants. The boundary condition and Eqs. $(3)$ then allow to express them as functions of a single parameter, $s$.

Thanks, I will remember that each equation should be assigned with an integration constant.
